# Is there any way to read the image in the page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, fileapi

I wonder if there's any way to read the images in the web page 
cause I want to make a small plugin that can upload them to my server, 
First,I set the images draggable and then I drap them to a small "box" and upload them, 
Maybe the *File API* in *HTML5*,But I found it can only read local file unfortunately,
Anyone get some ideas?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with images (croping, resizeing etc) you have to use HTML5 `<canvas>` element. But if you just want to have an image element, you can use this:

```
var myImg = new Image();
myImg.src = "url_to_image";
```

Comment: well,image is just the begining,I want to upload everything you see in the web page,Including the audio,video,etc. Any ideas?

Comment: can you explain your goal in more details? what do you really want to do with that content and from where it is?

Comment: For example ,just an example, If I'm in google.com,and I like the logo ,so I drap it to my plugin box(in chrome),and the logo image will be uploaded to my server,thanks,

Comment: for that you can just pass the URL of the picture to the server and get it by URL server-side using for example PHP's `getfilecontents()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to copy images from some page to your server? You can get page source, all images links and display it in javascript, but to upload it to your server you have to use one of server side languages like e.g. PHP.

Comment: My question is:how to upload it, I want the xhr.send(file),But how can I exactly get the *file*,Thanks